# Problem with command frac at position 2:0_Unknown symbol or command or predefined TeXFormula: 'normalsubformula'

Tags: java, formula

### On parsing the latex formula using TexIcon, its not able to render the svg,getting the below mentioned error and missing the respective formula

### ERROR LOG:
Problem with command frac at position 2:0_Unknown symbol or command or predefined TeXFormula: 'normalsubformula'

### HOW TO REPRODUCE THE BUG:

1.Pass the latex as input in TeXFormula.
2.new TeXFormula(formula); is giving the error

Comment: Are you referring to a java class named `TeXFormula`? If so, then I found several such classes when I searched the Internet. In order to **REPRODUCE THE BUG** I need to know which `TeXFormula` class to use.

Comment: Thanks Abra,Yes Abra, I am referring to java class TexFormula , I have one latex formula where it should be parsed using TexFormula and that latex should be rendered as a svg formula using TexIcon